# "Unable to find root device" on a fresh ArchLinux install

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, macbook-pro

I have installed the latest version of ArchLinux (2014.06.01) on a MacBook Pro 8,1 (15", if that matters regarding hardware) dual-booting with OSX following the instructions in the [official install guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide). However, when try and reboot into the newly installed system, it drops me into a recovery shell:

```
ERROR: device 'UUID=<snip>' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device 'UUID=<snip>'.
You are being dropped to a recovery shell
    Type 'exit' to try and continue booting
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs /]#
```

(I removed the UUID because I didn't want to type it out, but it is the same as the one given to me by `blkid` (from the install disk) for the partition ArchLinux is installed on)

[Other](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135288) [online](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1311047) [sources](http://fanweiphysicist.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/unable-to-find-root-device-archlinux.html) suggest this is due to an outdated `pacman`, `udev`, `filesystem` or `linux` package. However, they describe this problem only after a kernel update from a working system, not a fresh install. I force-reinstalled these packages from the `arch-chroot` environment while booted to the install disk, but that did not change the situation.

Instead, a little bit of experimentation with my `grub.cfg` shows that whatever is complained about is the `root` parameter to the `linux` command selecting what `vmlinuz` file to use. Indeed, changing `root=UUID=<snip>` to `root=LABEL=ArchLinux` or `root=/dev/sda8` (both describe where ArchLinux is installed and I have certainly used the second version successfully before with another distribution) gives `Unable to find root device 'LABEL=ArchLinux'` and `Unable to find root device '/dev/sda8'` respectively. Furthermore, GRUB seems to be able to find the partition by UUID, only the linux kernel complains about it not being found, as the initial ramdisk is properly loaded (ie. this is not a GRUB error as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/359417/linux-installation-wont-boot-due-to-grub-no-such-device-error) but rather a linux error).

As a side note: the recovery shell is severely limited, and standard output does not appear to work properly. Nevertheless, `ls` works, and listing files shows a basic (temporary) file system, but all disk devices appear to be missing from `/dev`. However, I don't know if this is part of the error or not.

This is similar, but not the same as [Linux doesn't find root file system when booting](https://superuser.com/questions/759311/linux-doesnt-find-root-file-system-when-booting), as the partition was *ext4* from the beginning. Also not exactly the same, but maybe relevant is [Unable to boot ArchLinux on Macbook Pro 7.1 - drops to recovery shell](https://superuser.com/questions/318866/unable-to-boot-archlinux-on-macbook-pro-7-1-drops-to-recovery-shell), however, there, it drops into a `ramfs` shell instead of a `rootfs` shell and the error messages differ.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of booting with the normal image, I used the fallback version and managed to boot into the system. As it turns out, Linux could not detect any drives due to the `block` `mkinitcpio` hook (responsible for block devices) missing from the default image. This was due to it being placed after `autodetect` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. To fix this, the `HOOKS=...` line in that file needs to be changed so that `block` comes before `autodetect`

*Before the fix:*

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect block modconf filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

*After the fix:*

```
HOOKS="base udev block autodetect modconf filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

Running `mkinitcpio -p linux` to regenerate the `initramfs`then fixed the problem permanently.

Comment: It was very helpful :)

Comment: This seems hard to reproduce, I had the same problem and this fixed it but the same drive worked perfectly fine on another pc. The pc where the problem occurred was a rather old LGA775 pc and the solution above was not necessary when using a mbr partition table. So the problem only occurred when using a  gpt partition table on an old system without UEFI .  I don't know if Macs always use EFI but I wonder which partition table did you use ?

Comment: It's been a while, and the MacBook is no more, but I'm fairly sure it used GPT.

Comment: Although, I'm getting the same issues as OP and your answer seems to apply to me, it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: You, my friend, you are the real MVP! This saved me after **many** hours of debug/crying

Comment: Where did you get the `fallback version` image?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue but with a different setup. I'm using ArchLinux in a virtual machine and my bootloader is syslinux. I used your trick on switching the kernel hooks order but I still ended up in a rootfs-shell.

What fixed the issue for me was changing the `APPEND` line in my `syslinux.cfg` from

```
APPEND root=UUID=<snip>
```

to

```
APPEND root=PARTUUID=<snip>
```

You can easily append the `PARTUUID` to the `syslinux.cfg` by using a command like `blkid | grep sda1 | awk '{ print $7 }' >> /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` assuming your root partition is `/dev/sda1`

Afterwards you can use your favorite text-editor to move the line to the appropriate space.

EDIT: I just recognized that the column number in the small awk script may vary, so better have a look at the output before piping it into `syslinux.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Dell XPS 15 (2021). I resolved it by changing the `SATA/NVMe Operation` setting in the bios from `RAID On` to `AHCI/NVMe`.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled with the same error when I installed Arch to the flash drive.

I looked into `/usr/lib/initcpio/init_functions` script and found solution for that case:

- Mount required partition when you are in initramfs:
  `mount /dev/sdx8 /new_root/`
- Press Ctrl+D to boot into linux.
- Edit `/etc/default/grub`, add rootdelay=90 to linux command line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootdelay=90"`.
- Update grub: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.